# Can I save bulk update screens for future use?

Tags: profile, smartgroups

I'm not sure if my title is 100% clear, but here's the situation I'm facing.

We have custom fields that once a year we have to manually update for all current members. A smart group was created to find all current (paid) members and a profile that shows the username and the two custom fields we need to update. To initiate the bulk update, we do the following:

- Click on Manage Groups
- Click on the Contacts link of the group in question
- Select all entries
- From the Actions drop down list, select Update multiple Contacts
- On the next screen, select the profile for updating the appropriate fields
- Click Continue

Now, we can update the necessary fields, click Update Contacts and we're done.

Is there a way to save that bulk update screen for later re-use. Ideally, I'd like to be able to save it for easy access from the menu much like a report. Not only would it be quicker to access, but also simpler when training someone else to make these updates. Basically, it should remember the Smart Group and Profile used to create it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [search action designer extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/searchactiondesigner) to design your own bulk update actions.

Comment: Thank you. I will have that installed on our test server and see if it solves my problem.